# Content-type not working in PHP

Tags: php, apache, content-type, wamp

I have some issues with a PHP file that is not working properly. The Content-type does not get recieved by any browser at all. Firebug interprets the file as text/html instead of css. Here's the file :

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/css; charset=UTF-8');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
/* CSS goes on from here */
```

I tested to put a row with `echo 'TEST';` before the header line, and was expecting to see the classic "headers already sent" error, but nothing appears!

Normal .css-files are working like a charm however.

What can I do  to sort this out?

**UPDATE:**
Did change `default_mimetype = "text/html"` to `default_mimetype = "text/css"` in php.ini and all pages got immediately interpreted as css, so there's must be a way to just send css headers for this file :)

The full file from demand of John:

```
    <?php
    header('Content-Type: text/css; charset=UTF-8');
    echo 'body {background-color: #000000; }';
    ?>
```

**UPDATE #2:**
Adding `ini_set('default_mimetype', 'text/css');` to the PHP file fixes this file, but it doesn't solve the issue that causes this fault...

**UPDATE #3:**
Tested adding `AddType text/css .css` to both .htaccess and Apache config. Still no luck. Also tested to send headers separated from charset: `header('Content-Type: text/css');` - Still no luck...

**UPDATE #4:**
Have reinstalled Apache+PHP at the server to see if the problem goes away, but no. Same old, same old...

Comment: Can you see what headers are sent to the browsers in Figrebug?

Comment: I know this is a silly question, but are you closing the <?php before you output the css? Of course if you're echoing the css, ignore me.

Comment: Hi Matt! Yep! The css is echoed, thanks!

Comment: Thanks industrial! I tested the code and it outputs the css fine (and with the correct mime type). Try changing 'display_errors' to 'On' in php.ini. There is definitely some funky error occurring but not being displayed. Edit: Do you know if you're using mod_php or FastCGI with apache?

Comment: Hi! From what I can tell, I'm using mod_php. Errors are on, but nothing appears :(

Comment: Ok guys, No one has any idea left?

Comment: is the actual css being sent to the browser ?

Comment: Industrial: what is the extension of your file css or php?

Comment: The css is sent, but read as HTML as described.

Comment: The css file is loaded up by a php file, so the stylesheet linked is a php file.

Comment: And you absolutely, definitely, cross-your-heart-and-hope-to-die, don't have any whitespace before the `<?php`?

Comment: I have tried all the answers, and Firefox Network Developer Tool still tells me that the .js file returned by my router.php is of type html instead of JavaScript. In Chrome the type is reported as "script". So this really looks like a bug in Firefox. I wish I could ask my own question and provide my code, but I'm not allowed to post questions here, only comments and answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check your php.ini file for the output_buffering setting. If it's not set to "off" than PHP is automatically doing output buffering for you. Set that to off and echo something before the header command, and you should see the "classic error".

You shouldn't use the closing ?>. I know this is a controversial suggestion, but too many times people add a return and/or space after it, which gets output to the browser (before the header). There are very few cases where it not using it would cause a problem.

Comment: This isn't controversial anymore (at least, not since June 2012).  [PSR-2 explicitly forbids using the closing `?>` at the end of a file](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/#2-2-files).

Answer (score 5):

1. Make sure your file editor **doesn't** save a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark) in your PHP file.
2. Try to move error_reporting / ini_set to make them the firsts PHP statements (before header() call). This way you will see all errors (if any). **Don't forget to put that OFF in production!**
3. Silly remark, but make sure this file is interpreted as PHP (extension is .php or if not an .htaccess tell the server to interpret as PHP).
4. Everything else is fine with your code. If it still doesn't work, check your server logs. Maybe something else crashes the execution of this PHP file (invalid MIME or else)...

Comment: Hi! Nothing in the server logs. I'll try your first tstep now and get back. Thanks

Comment: You might want to add the `Content-Type` property can be overridden in the .htaccess file(s). (e.g. `ForceType` and `AddType`)

Answer (score 3):

the reason is because the `header` function works only if it is the first one to be called!

If you put an `echo` before, the content type automatically becomes `text/html`

try to print a CSS code after the header to test if it actually works.

Read [this page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) for more infos

EDIT: did you change your post ? :-)

Comment: Hi man! Yep, edited the post to make it a bit clearer. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

This is usually caused by a fatal error (ie, syntax error) that causes the script to abort before any of the code is execute (before display_errors can be set through ini_set() at runtime). Try changing display_errors in the php config file (php.ini).

Comment: Actually cleaned out the whole file, and just had the header line there. It still doesn't want to interpret as CSS.

Comment: Post the css, something is causing a fatal error. Which is why the echo statement at the bottom didn't do anything and php errors aren't being displayed. There could be something in your css that is breaking the script (especially true if you're echo'ing it, its easy to miss an unescaped quote)

Comment: Hi John, posted up the full file in the first post, even though it's just one line of Css that should be valid...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the function `header()` is disabled in your configuration?

Test:

```
print ini_get('disable_functions');
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be worth checking with [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) to see what headers are actually being sent.

Try this from a command line and check for the "text/css":

```
curl -I http://example.com
```

Depending on the browser's request headers, PHP could also be sending the output gzipped using output buffering. In the PHP file, try this to check for `ob_gzhandler`.

```
print_r(ob_list_handlers());
```

If it's enabled, check in for `zlib.output_compression` in your php.ini or Apache configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I found the full file is indented.

```
    <?php
    header('Content-Type: text/css; charset=UTF-8');
    echo 'body {background-color: #000000; }';
    ?>
```

Because the indentation on line 1 outputted 4 spaces, therefore, the header will not work.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like your webserver is interpreting the script as a normal file. Does it have a .php extension and do other .php files work as expected?

Comment: Hi! It sure does. Everything else is working like a charm and Mod_rewrite is enabled as well!

Answer (score 0):

Looks perfectly ok and the line with the `echo` should definitely generate a warning. Could it be that you're editing the wrong file?

Comment: I'm afraid not, thats the first in my checklist to try :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Content-Style-Type: text/css`

See the below from the [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/present/styles.html)

`<META http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">`

> The default style sheet language may also be set with
>   HTTP headers. The above META
>   declaration is equivalent to the HTTP
>   header:
>
> `Content-Style-Type: text/css`

**Edit:**

At the [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Incorrect_MIME_Type_for_CSS_Files) , it's mentionned to add `AddType text/css .css` in the apache config file.
Maybe you can give it a try

**Edit2**
Look up for 'css' at this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php). Someone had the same problem as you. Try sending the header without the charset

> I recently had a hair-threatening
>   problem with Firefox and XHTML 1.0
>   transitional.
>
> It worked fine with other browsers,
>   and also with HTML 4.1.
>
> To cut a long story short,
>   PHP-generated JS and CSS files were
>   still being reported by the headers as
>   text/html, while in the HTML they were
>   text/css and application/javascript;
>   Firefox having been told the page was
>   XHTML 1.0 became anal-retentive and
>   refused to style the page. (I think
>   the JS still worked but I fixed it
>   anyway.)
>
> Solution:
>
> header('Content-type: text/css'); and
>   header('Content-type:
>   application/javascript');

**Edit 3**
There was a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347868/firefox-upload-form-issue) about some forms not submitting any data because of an utility called AVG Linkscanner. Since you have reinstalled Apache + php and I assume you didn't reinstall the OS, so you can maybe investigate on this/try by turning some utilities/plugs-ins off.

Comment: Nope! Didn't change anything I'm afraid :(

Comment: Hi again. Tried to send just the content-type without any charset earlier. Nothing new. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The "default style sheet language" applies to the style **attribute**, style elements take their language from the required type attribute, linked stylesheets take theirs from the HTTP header.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess : open your file with something which would display any [BOM](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark). If you see some strange characters before `<?php` you have your problem. Check your current editor options to save UTF-8 file and make it save them without BOM.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are issues with caching.

Try this:

```
header('Content-type: text/css');
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");

echo 'body {background-color: #000000; }';
```

Works for me on an out of the box XAMPP installation and firefox - firebug reports correct content type.

Answer (score 0):

`output_buffering = Off` in php.ini was the reason for me why it keeps sending `Content-Type = text/html`. Setting it to 1 solves it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I struggled for hours with my code `header('text/javascript');`, wondering why the response MIME type wasn't being sent. The correct PHP code is `header('Content-type: text/javascript');`. There is no proper error detection for this programming error in PHP, Apache, the browsers, or the Web Developer Tools.