# Using GD on PHP does not work - only black square

Tags: php, gd, php-7.2

I'm trying to draw a simple image with `GD` on `PHP 7.2.5` on my Server (Debian 4.9.88-1+deb9u1).

My source code looks simply like that:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    header("Content-type: image/png");
    $string = $_GET['text'];
    $im     = imagecreatefromjpeg("test.jpg");
    $orange = imagecolorallocate($im, 220, 210, 60);
    $px     = (imagesx($im) - 7.5 * strlen($string)) / 2;
    imagestring($im, 3, $px, 9, $string, $orange);
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);

?>
```

test.jpg is available in the same folder.
PHP-Version: 7.2.5
I can't see anything related in the log files.

GD is activated on the server:

[image]

Result looks like that:

[Result of the previous shown source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaBOC.png)

Comment: Your code works for me on PHP 7.1.18.  Try it with a different JPG file.

Comment: @timclutton I tried it now with a similar picture - no success. Could it be a right related issue? Or must it be a "JPEG" instead of "JPG"?

Comment: That would be my first guess.  Try a simple one line script like: `var_dump(file_get_contents('test.jpg'));` and confirm your script reads  data from the file.

Comment: For my `image.jpg` it displays `bool(false)` but for another jpg a content is shown.
But there's no change when I set 777 as rights.

Comment: nevermind... The output of `image.jpg` looks like: [link](https://imgur.com/a/ACN8EnP)

Comment: Ok, that's not a JPG.  It looks like a PSD file, at a guess.

Comment: Okay, but the pic from the internet also looks like that: [link](https://imgur.com/a/g4BvAul)

Comment: Ah, slightly different, but I guess that reference is the EXIF data about the package used to create the image.  My mistake.  So, it looks like you can read the file; now check if GD can load the image: `var_dump(imagecreatefromjpeg('test.jpg'));` It should return something like `resource(3, gd)`.

Comment: `resource(3) of type (gd)`

(btw. thanks for your effort!)

Comment: @timclutton I've tested it one more time. Everything works fine until this line is added:
`header("Content-type: image/png");`

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by following this answer:
[header('Content-Type: image/png'); not working anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22561073/headercontent-type-image-png-not-working-anymore)

The problem was that my .php file was not in ANSI but in UTF-8, after converting it to ANSI it worked.