# Open a file in the browser served from PHP

Tags: php, file, browser, mime-types, userfrosting

Simple question, probably been asked a million times but I've searched and am no closer to getting this to work.

I have a PHP script within the UserFrosting framework that serves a file to the user via their browser.  I would like the file to open in their browser if they select 'Open' insteand of download.

Problem is, the only things that are opening properly are text files. Anything else (PDFs and JPGs tested so far) are just opening as a page of ASCII/garbled code instead of being interpreted as a PDF or an image.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
header('Content-Type: '. $mime);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($diskname));
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=' . $savename);
return readfile($diskname);
```

`$mime` is the Mime type of the file set via a function, so could be `application/pdf` or `image/jpeg` for the files I'm trying to view so far.

Does anyone have any ideas why the files aren't opening properly?

**UPDATE**
Having checked the response headers, I'm getting a Content Type of `text/html;charset=UTF-8` instead of the `application/jpeg` or `application/pdf` that it should have been set to according to the code I'm using.  I'm wondering if this is a UserFrosting issue?

Comment: "could be application/pdf or image/jpeg " — Have you checked that that is what the server is actually sending?

Comment: Well $mime is definitely being set to either application/pdf or image/jpeg depending on the file.  My browser debug-fu isn't great though (using Firefox), the file is being 'opened' in a new tab and there's an error popping up saying, "The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared."  I'm assuming the Content-Type is getting lost somehow?

Comment: Open the developer tools. Look at the Network tab. Load the page. It will show you all the requests and responses and let you examine the headers and raw content.

Comment: Okay - in the Response Headers, Content-Type is coming back as `text/html;charset=UTF-8` - which is clearly not what I was setting it to before sending the file. Could Markus Laubenthal be on to something with the empty spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, problem solved.  As I suspected, it was to do with the UserFrosting framework, or more specifically, Slim.

Instead of settings the headers using `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');`, I should have been doing the following:

```
$this->_app->response->headers->set('Content-Type', $mime);
```

Problem solved. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since i can't comment cause of reputation, i'll have to answer, even if I am not 100% sure that this is your problem.

The thing is, sometimes PHP-files can cause a lot of trouble.

```
 <--- this little empty line
<?
code goes here
?>
 <--- or this one
```

The marked empty line can destroy your header. Have you checked all your files for empty lines which are interpreted as content instead of PHP-Code?

Enabling warnings can help in this matter too. If there is any content before setting the headers you normally would get a warning which states exactly this.

We had this once in our company and it costs 3 of our devs nearly a whole day to find because... reasons.

**EDIT:** Seeing your comment "The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared." actually underlines my statement. Anyway not 100% sure tho.

Comment: I have error reporting set to `E_ALL` in php.ini, so I'm assuming I should be seeing warnings if they are being generated, but I'm getting nothing in the error log..?

Comment: The rest of the header is intact though - it's just the Content Type that's getting changed.. :/

Comment: well, have a look at this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2649879/6479510). It gives some deeper information into the same problem with the content-type. I'm pretty sure there has to be some output in one of your files anywhere.

Comment: FYI: [PSR-2 explicitly forbids using `?>` at the end of a file](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/#2-2-files).