# Content-Type Header in PHP

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I am creating a wordpress plugin which fetched some data and then echos a `json_encode`.

This is being done by creating a function and calling it from a shortcode.

The shortcode is being injected in blank page template from wordpress pages.

I am trying to set the header to application/json in the function of the shortcode plugin however this is being ignore and the content type is still set to HTML/TEXT.

I am setting the header this way:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

The whole plugin thing looks like this:

```
<?php function abc_func(){

    header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

    $abc_array = array(
                    'abc' => $abc
    );

    echo json_encode($abc_array);

}

add_shortcode('abc_shortcode', 'abc_func');

?>
```

Comment: before the shortcode there is another output?

Comment: In the chain of function calls, maybe somewhere in the wordpress implementation you are using it is overwriting / nulling the header content type?

Comment: @ZiTAL - I have updated the question including how im developing the plugin

Comment: @JokerDan thats what I was thinking, can I somehow overwrite that through this shortcode implementation ?

Comment: after `echo json_encode($abc_array);` put an `exit();` to probe if there is something after that changes the headers

Comment: @ZiTAL this still didnt change the header

Comment: use this function to remove content-type before you set it: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header-remove.php

Comment: @ZiTAL this still didnt replace the content type

Comment: Last chance: https://coderwall.com/p/tkveyq/how-to-change-http-header-content-type-in-wordpress

Answer (score 0):

This may cause if before setting header (or before your plugin code), some data was sent to output, make sure you'r setting header before those.

Answer (score 0):

> Check your php.ini file for the output_buffering setting. If it's not
>   set to "off" than PHP is automatically doing output buffering for you.
>   Set that to off and echo something before the header command, and you
>   should see the "classic error".

[Content-type not working in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508718/content-type-not-working-in-php)

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

Is there any place that changed the content type later?

**Edited 2017-03-02**

[Content-type not working in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508718/content-type-not-working-in-php)

> Check your php.ini file for the output_buffering setting. If it's not
>   set to "off" than PHP is automatically doing output buffering for you.
>   Set that to off and echo something before the header command, and you
>   should see the "classic error".

Comment: Nope, after implementing that, still the content type is set to: Content-Type:text/html; charset="UTF-8"