# PHP function call from HTML to set img src (same file)

Tags: php, html, image

I'm generating a captcha image with PHP.
I was calling "captcha.php" to set `img src=""` like this:

```
<img src="captcha.php">
```

Then I merged the files and inserted all the PHP code in a function and when I try to call the function in img src like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo generateCaptcha();?>>
```

It gives me a black page.

PHP relevant code:

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($Immagine);
imagedestroy($Immagine);`
```

HTML call:

```
<img src="<?php echo generateCaptcha();?>" id="CaptchaImg" name="CaptchaImg"/>
```

Am I getting a problem with the return value of the function?
Is HTML struggling with the image extension?
What's going wrong and how can I fix it?

function code:

```
<?php function generateCaptcha(){

session_start();

$stringa = '';

for($i=0; $i<5; $i++)
    switch(rand (0, 2)){
        case 0:
            $stringa .= chr(rand(97, 122));
            break;
        case 1:
            $stringa .= chr(rand(65, 90));
            break;
        case 2:
            $stringa .= chr(rand(48, 57)); }

#print "$stringa";

$_SESSION["Codice_Captcha"] = $stringa;
$Immagine = imagecreatetruecolor(160, 60);

$r=rand(0,75);
$g=rand(0,75);
$b=rand(0,75);

$coloreSfondo = imagecolorallocate($Immagine, $r, $g, $b);
$coloreScritta = imagecolorallocate($Immagine, 255-$r, 255-$g, 255-$b);

imagefilledrectangle($Immagine,0,0,230,130,$coloreSfondo);
$fontType="fonts/".rand(0,49).".ttf";

switch(rand(0,2)){#permutations of the image}

imagettftext($Immagine, 30, rand(-5, 5), 10, 45, $coloreScritta, $fontType, $_SESSION["Codice_Captcha"]);


imagesetthickness($Immagine, 2);

switch(rand(0,8)){#permutations of the image }

header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($Immagine);
imagedestroy($Immagine);}?>
```

Comment: Gives you a black page!?

Comment: yes, it does. a black page with a small white empty square in the middle.

Comment: Can we see your `generateCaptcha()` function?

Comment: Is it the image that is black, or the page where the image is that is black? obviously the first one. Post your function's code **in your question**.

Comment: This is the generateCaptcha(); code but no is not the image black

Comment: it doestn't show the site itself it show a black page instead which it shouldn't

Comment: I made some progress and now instead the page load but where the image should be there is :"��+�1h���KO\��[��F�I���??~��n�!" and goes on for a while and ends with id="CaptchaImg" name="CaptchaImg"/>

Comment: That seems like your `header()` isn't working correctly. Maybe related: [Content-type not working in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508718/content-type-not-working-in-php).

Comment: So what i should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest checking your server logs for errors.

You have to call `header()` before any other output. But, in your code, the page outputs the first part of the `<img>` tag before calling the function that executes `header()`. This will probably throw an error. Also, I think the line below will throw an error because the `#` comments out the closing brace:

```
switch(rand(0,2)){#permutations of the image}
```

---

I suggest changing the function to output base64 encoded image data.
Then you can echo the function's returned value into the `<img>`.

Something like this:

```
<?php

function generateCaptcha(){

  $Immagine = imagecreatetruecolor(160, 60);

  $r=rand(0,75);
  $g=rand(0,75);
  $b=rand(0,75);

  $coloreSfondo = imagecolorallocate($Immagine, $r, $g, $b);
  $coloreScritta = imagecolorallocate($Immagine, 255-$r, 255-$g, 255-$b);

  imagefilledrectangle($Immagine,0,0,230,130,$coloreSfondo);

  ob_start();
  imagepng($Immagine);
  $image_data = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();

  imagedestroy($mmagine);

  return 'data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($image_data);

}

?><img src="<?=generateCaptcha()?>">
```

Comment: The problem was Just the return type